# Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease' - ':video_player_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, android-video-player

When i try to generate the signed APK i am getting this below error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':video_player_android:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar.
         > Failed to transform '/Users/elamparithibalakrishnan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

But i can able build the signed Bundle file. This is not the first time i am generating the apk for this app. But dont know y i got this error.

can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this in the gradle.properties fixed my issue.

```
android.jetifier.blacklist=bcprov-jdk15on
```